# Error 'access violation at adress'

Tags: debugging

Is there a simple way to solve for a 'Access violation at address 00447987. Read of address 00000000.' error?

All I am doing is running input on LEM (statistical software like R, but less developed). Other models have worked so its not a general problem.

I searched the net for solutions, but these are mostly answered by programmers who seem to have Delphi on there pc, and I don't. I'm not familiar with the technicalities. I updated my audio drive, deleted and reinstalled the file of the program, restarted my pc.

If it would help the program is small and can be downloaded here:
http://members.home.nl/jeroenvermunt/

- second under the download section.
- the filename cannot contain any spaces
- I know other people get also an error

This is the input I use:

```
dim 4 3 2 4 2
lab V E A F G
mod {VEAFG}
dat [
1 0 9 7 2 10 1 3 
4 1 1 2 2 2 0 2
3 0 9 11 7 5 0 4
1 2 5 7 3 3 1 3
6 1 14 9 1 5 1 1 
5 1 20 11 1 5 0 1
2 2 20 12 3 1 0 1
0 1 5 8 0 5 0 1
7 3 7 10 3 2 0 0 
4 4 16 19 0 8 0 1
6 6 19 20 0 4 0 0
3 0 10 10 2 3 0 1
11 3 36 21 5 14 0 3
5 1 24 7 3 4 0 3
13 6 27 42 8 17 0 2
25 13 46 76 9 27 0 3
21 10 23 39 4 13 0 1
26 11 47 40 3 8 0 2 
19 6 51 27 2 7 0 2
12 4 40 23 8 12 1 5 
14 8 21 31 2 5 0 1
24 16 33 51 1 10 1 2
12 15 28 33 2 11 0 2 
15 8 27 17 2 9 0 1
]
```

Comment: The way you solve this is to use a debugger.

Comment: Not sure this is the right place to help you. Debugging someone else's code is pretty hard even if you're fluent in the language concerned, which you probably aren't? (Also that download doesn't seem to contain source code, so you couldn't even debug the source.) You might be better off getting in touch with the program's author, or other users. Or just modifying your input a bit and working around the problem (or using an alternative tool for this input).

Comment: Thanks, I expected maybe there was a way I could empty that address on my pc so that it could be used. No such simple solution apparently! Will contact the author.

Answer (score 2):

00447987 is the memory address of the code that is trying to access memory at address 00000000 (ie a NULL pointer)  You would load the program into a debugger and have it jump to address 00447987, which will show you the compiled machine code, and if the program has debug symbols and/or a map file, or a little manual analysis, will help you locate the original source code.

Comment: Any tips on where to find an appropriate debug program?

Comment: The one built in to the IDE that was used to create the program in the first place. If you are not the author of the program, then file a bug report with the author and let him/her debug it.